# Can Ubuntu be installed on Windows 7 drive that is encrypted with Truecrypt?

Tags: installation, windows-7, truecrypt

I've been looking everywhere.  Truecrypt forums and over the Ubuntu forums.  I have yet to find an answer that comes close to my issue or question.  My computer came with Windows 7 preinstalled so I have no live disc.  The more I get to know Ubuntu the more I grow to love it.  I have tried to install Ubuntu along side Windows 7 on both C and D drives of the encrypted disk.  When I restart truecrypt asks for password like normal then on first go will load ubuntu, but Ubuntu will start then go to a screen with error messages.  Off the top of my head it was on the lines of "network time out" or 'time expired error."  I really am getting sick of Windows.  To much garbage in its being.  Is there anyway to get the installation to run after the whole system is encrypted?  Or will I have to unencrypt, install, then re-encrypt (huge pain in the butt if so for wait time as it writes over)?  Any help on this would be wonderful.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this howto in the Ubuntu forum? 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=761530

It describes how to setup an dual boot environment with full encryption.